# Linking Voucher to Invoice

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to link the receipt vouchers paid to the invoices number, 
Using `=VLOOKUP(C6;[Sheet2]$A$1:$G$1000;2;FALSE)` helps when the "invoice number" is in column A, while in my case the "receipt voucher" number is in column A and the invoices numbers are in columns C, E, F G.. etc.. (depending on how many invoices are paid using the same receipt voucher)

Clarification:

assume I have issued 9 invoices (#1-#9) to my customers. Their amounts and details are as below:

```
Amount  Customer       Date   Invoice #    Receipt Voucher #
 100    Customer A  15-Oct-16   1   
  25    Customer B  16-Oct-16   2   
 123    Customer A  17-Oct-16   3   
 100    Customer A  18-Oct-16   4   
  11    Customer C  19-Oct-16   5   
 100    Customer A  20-Oct-16   6   
  90    Customer A  21-Oct-16   7   
  50    Customer A  22-Oct-16   8   
 160    Customer B  23-Oct-16   9
```

(This is the format my POS system issues in, column A is the amount, Column B is the customer name, column C is the date and column D is the invoice number)

and I am making another excel file for the receipt vouchers that I issue when I got the payment, a voucher might be for one or more invoices as below:

```
Receipt voucher #   Date        Amount    Invoices Paid by the voucher          
   33              15-Nov-16    125.00          1   2       
   45              17-Nov-16    223.00          3   4       
   55              18-Nov-16     11.00          5           
  123              20-Nov-16    400.00          6   7   8   9
```

now my question is, when I enter the data in the receipt voucher details file (in the second table), how can I make excel put the receipt voucher number beside the related invoice number in the first table.

Comment: Please add some sample data. It's difficult to understand your question now.

Comment: Clarification: 

assume I issued 9 invoices (#1-#9). The details are as below: 

[Table 1][1]

(This is the format my POS system issues in) 

and I am making another excel file for the receipt vouchers that I issue when I get payments, one voucher is for one or more invoices as below: 

[Table 2][2]

now my question is, when I enter data in the receipt voucher details file (Table 2), how can I make excel put the receipt voucher number beside the related invoice number in the first table. 

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkeNk.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z358t.png